# Suppose given a word "ABC" then rankweight equals (1+2+3)/3 how to achieve this in SAS

Tags: sas

Suppose I want to calculate the rankweight of "ABD" that is (1+2+4)/3 in SAS. How to do it. thanks

Comment: Would you care to explain a bit more with a suitable example?

Comment: Do you want to use the same weighting for upper and lower case letters? What about non-alphabetic characters?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're trying to do something like this?

```
data _null_;
    text = "ABD";
    n = length(text);
    ranksum = 0;
    do i = 1 to n;
        ranksum + rank(lowcase(substr(text,i,1)));
    end;
    rankweight = ranksum / n - 96; /*rank('a') = 97*/
    put _all_;
run;
```